# MYSQL Grouping timestamps by day when retrieving

Tags: mysql

i have thousands of timestamps, is it possible to get MySQL to sort these into a day / count array? Rather then doing it via PHP or JS.

The basic query is basically

```
$mysqli->query("SELECT datetime FROM `users` WHERE `datetime`");
```

And i need to present them on to a chart that takes date / count values. Id like to display it in a daily interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select date(datetime) as `day`, count(*)
from your_table
group by date(datetime)
```

Comment: That was fast! Thanks a bunch, i will accept as soon as i can :-)